# How to Manually Deploy a Rails App with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, version-control, deployment

I'm New to Rails, I want to deploy my first app. I realized there are many steps involved in deployment.

What are all the necessary steps in deploying a rails app, that is using Git as VCS.

If explaining all parts is not possible, list the tasks that need to be done and a summary of it.

I know there is capistrano to help automate those tasks, But, I like to know what is going on, so that I can automate later with capistrano, with more educated judgements.

Comment: http://hostingrails.com/How-to-Deploy-Rails-Using-Git-with-Capistrano-on-Mongrel-with-HostingRails could help

Answer (score 3):

Use Heroku or EngineYard as these are the main cloud hosting solutions today (they both are backed onto Amazon and leverage EC2 and the EBS)

They both have great instructions on how to use git with them:

Heroku:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Engine Yard: http://docs.engineyard.com/host-your-code-on-github.html

In choosing, Heroku is more full-service whereas Engine Yard is a more traditional service, giving you access to boxes but needing sysadmin skills.

Comment: Thanks, I've researched, and found deploying Rails app on Heroku is so easy with Heroku Gem(before posting this question). But, Heroku seems costly for me. Also, I guess it will be helpful in the long run to know, what exactly is going on during deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Git hooks and use one for a post-push that will execute any thing that needs to be done to update your Rails app after it's been pushed.